# BigQuery SQL to change start date and end date into groups of months

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I work with a hotel client where they have a BigQuery database which has hotel booking data. I've shared the relevant columns in the image below which list the names of each hotel, the arrival date of the guest, the departure date, and the revenue generated from the each booking:

[image]

My problem statement is that I have to showcase how many rooms have been booked, and how much revenue has been made for each hotel every month where my final grid would look similar to this:

[image]

The important points to remember are:

- the `depart_dt - arrival_dt` are the number of nights that the guest is staying
- the `Rez_rate_total / (depart_dt - arrival_dt)` is the revenue made per night

My problem here is trying to figure out how to change the start date and end date columns into groups of months. The challenge comes when a guest arrives in one month and leaves in the next month. For example, Row 5 in the original data has the guest coming in on 18th July and leaving on 1st Aug - so 13 days of his stay and 13 days of revenue has to be included in July and 1 day has to be included in August.

I haven't used SQL in a while so this is as far as I got:

```
WITH
  temp_table AS (
  SELECT
    hotel_long_nm,
    arrival_dt,
    depart_dt,
    DATE_DIFF(depart_dt, arrival_dt, day) AS room_nights,
    rez_rate_total
  FROM
    `DATABASE.analytics.bookings` )
SELECT
  *
FROM
  temp_table
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure that Hotel 3 should cross over into August? I can answer your question either way, but most hotels book/charge for the night, you don't pay on the date you leave.  If I booked a 14-day hotel stay starting on July 18, I would expect to pay the evenings of July 18 thru July 31, then check out on Aug 1 (with no charge).  For a more trivial example, if you had a 1 night stay with arrival date on July 31 and a depart date on Aug 1, which month would you want that reservation?

Comment: You're correct about that. The departure date is the day they have to check out so this example was not correct - I've created dummy data based on my schema.  However the use case still stands. Also, if the arrival date is on July 31 and departure on Aug 1, the reservation will fall in July. I hope this answers your question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following approach:

```
with bookings as (
    select hotel_long_nm, date(arrival_dt) as arrival_dt, date(depart_dt) as depart_dt, rez_rate_total from project.dataset.bookings
),
tmp as (
    -- expose the dates in the reservation (excluding last day of reservation)
    select *, generate_date_array(arrival_dt,date_sub(depart_dt, interval 1 day)) as stay_dates from bookings
),
calc as (
    -- unnest and calculate the daily rate
    select
        hotel_long_nm, 
        stay_dt, 
        1 as stay_nights, 
        rez_rate_total/array_length(stay_dates) as rez_rate_daily
    from tmp
    left join unnest(stay_dates) as stay_dt
),
agg as (
    -- aggregate to the year-month level
    select
        date_trunc(stay_dt, month) as year_month,
        hotel_long_nm,
        sum(stay_nights) as room_nights,
        round(sum(rez_rate_daily),2) as rez_rate_total
    from calc
    group by 1,2
)
select * from agg
order by hotel_long_nm, year_month
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this is exactly what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this approach, following this logic.

- Validate if both dates are in the same month
- If are not in the same month, i get the final date of the month of
  arrival date and subtract both dates
- I get the first date of the month of the depart date and subtract
  and subtract both dates

In this code you can see an example:

```
SELECT
/*arrival date*/
CURRENT_DATE() AS the_arival,
/*depart_dt*/
DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AS the_depart,
/*total of night between arrival date and depart date*/
DATE_DIFF(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) , CURRENT_DATE(), DAY) AS total_room_nights,
/* validate if the dates are in the same month or different month if equal 0 same month if >0 another month */
DATE_DIFF(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) , CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH) AS Same_Month,/*1 no and 0 yes/
/*in this case are in different month*/
/*I get the final date of the arrival month and subtract with the arrival date*/
DATE_DIFF(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), INTERVAL 1 MONTH), MONTH), INTERVAL 1   DAY),DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), DAY) as total_room_nights_first_mont,
/*I get the initial date of the depart month and subtract with the depart date i add +1 because is the night between last day of the mont and first day of the next month*/
DATE_DIFF(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY),DATE_TRUNC(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 30 DAY), MONTH), DAY)+1 as total_room_nights_second_month
```

You can see more information about the date function.[Click Here.](https://copycoding.com/d/how-to-find-first-day-last-day-of-current-month-first-day-of-next-month-last-day-of-previous-month-in-google-bigquery)